# Limit Text Field to one decimal point input, numbers only, and two characters after the decimal place - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am struggling to do this with Swift 3. I have a text field that I would like to limit to only numbers and one decimal point and two characters after the decimal place. I would also like to have it work in regions where a decimal point is not used when entering non-integers. Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: " I would also like to have it work in regions where a decimal point is not used when entering non-integers." I don't get what you mean..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign delegate to your textfield and in the shouldChangeCharactersIn delegate method do your validations:

1. Add extension with validation methods for the string:

   ```
   extension String{

       private static let decimalFormatter:NumberFormatter = {
           let formatter = NumberFormatter()
           formatter.allowsFloats = true
           return formatter
       }()

       private var decimalSeparator:String{
           return String.decimalFormatter.decimalSeparator ?? "."
       }

       func isValidDecimal(maximumFractionDigits:Int)->Bool{

           // Depends on you if you consider empty string as valid number
           guard self.isEmpty == false else {
               return true
           }

           // Check if valid decimal
           if let _ = String.decimalFormatter.number(from: self){

               // Get fraction digits part using separator
               let numberComponents = self.components(separatedBy: decimalSeparator)
               let fractionDigits = numberComponents.count == 2 ? numberComponents.last ?? "" : ""
               return fractionDigits.characters.count <= maximumFractionDigits
           }

           return false
       }

   }
   ```
2. In your delegate method:

   ```
   func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

       // Get text
       let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
       let replacementText = (currentText as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

       // Validate
       return replacementText.isValidDecimal(maximumFractionDigits: 2)

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var number = Double(yourTextfield.text)
 if number != nil {
   //if user enters more than 2 digits after the decimal point it will round it up to 2
   let roundedNumber = Double(num!).roundTo(places: 2)  
 }
 else {
//probably print an error message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swift UI then the complete solution

1. TextField allow numeric value only
2. Should accept only one comma (".")
3. Restrict decimal point upto x decimal place

File NumbersOnlyViewModifier

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine
struct NumbersOnlyViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    @Binding var text: String
    var includeDecimal: Bool
    var digitAllowedAfterDecimal: Int = 1
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .keyboardType(includeDecimal ? .decimalPad : .numberPad)
            .onReceive(Just(text)) { newValue in
                var numbers = "0123456789"
                let decimalSeparator: String = Locale.current.decimalSeparator ?? "."
                if includeDecimal {
                    numbers += decimalSeparator
                }
                if newValue.components(separatedBy: decimalSeparator).count-1 > 1 {
                    let filtered = newValue
                    self.text = isValid(newValue: String(filtered.dropLast()), decimalSeparator: decimalSeparator)
                } else {
                    let filtered = newValue.filter { numbers.contains($0)}
                    if filtered != newValue {
                        self.text = isValid(newValue: filtered, decimalSeparator: decimalSeparator)
                    } else {
                        self.text = isValid(newValue: newValue, decimalSeparator: decimalSeparator)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    
    private func isValid(newValue: String, decimalSeparator: String) -> String {
        guard includeDecimal, !text.isEmpty else { return newValue }
        let component = newValue.components(separatedBy: decimalSeparator)
        if component.count > 1 {
            guard let last = component.last else { return newValue }
            if last.count > digitAllowedAfterDecimal {
                let filtered = newValue
               return String(filtered.dropLast())
            }
        }
        return newValue
    }
}
```

File View+Extenstion

```
extension View {
    func numbersOnly(_ text: Binding<String>, includeDecimal: Bool = false) -> some View {
        self.modifier(NumbersOnlyViewModifier(text: text, includeDecimal: includeDecimal))
    }
}
```

File ViewFile

```
 TextField("\(count, specifier: Constants.FloatFormat.twoDecimalFloat)", text: $value,  onEditingChanged: { isEditing in
      self.isEditing = isEditing
   }) 
  .foregroundColor(Color.neutralGray900)
  .numbersOnly($value, includeDecimal: true)
  .font(.system(size: Constants.FontSizes.fontSize22))
  .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
```